# inequality near $0$ with arbitrary norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Consider $a(x,y)= 2 x y - x^3+ x y^3$ and $b(x,y) = || (x,y)||^2$ for arbitrary norm. I want show that: $$|a(x,y)| \leq C |b(x,y)|$$ for $||(x,y)|| < \delta$ for $C, \delta >0$

Is there a general strategy since I do not know which norm I have to deal with?

Comment: Are the norms $p$-norms or even a more general one?

Comment: If $\max(|x|, |y|) \leq 1$ then $2xy \leq x^2 + y^2$, $x^3 \leq x^2$ and $xy^3 \leq y^2,$ so you can bound $|a(x,y)| \leq c \|(x,y)\|_2.$ And since all norms are equivalent in any finite (real) vecto space, we reach $|a(x,y)| \leq C b(x,y).$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When speaking about equivalent norms, in a sense that if $n_1(x)$ and $n_2(x)$ are different norms of $x$, we must have positive constants $c_1,c_2$ such that
$$c_1n_1(x)\le n_2(x)\le c_2n_1(x),$$then we can reduce the problem to the Euclidean norm and proceed.**

A good way to tackle these types of problems, is to work with bounds and inequalities rather than being too much strict. More specifically, start with showing that
$$
|a(x,y)|\le |2xy|+|x^3|+|xy^3|\le Cb(x,y)
$$
for some $C>0$ given $\delta>0$. The confidence in such an argument is that $x$ and $y$ cannot jump high and they always remain below a threshold ($\delta$). We continue as
$$
{
|2xy|<x^2+y^2
\\
|x^3|<\delta x^2
\\
|xy^3|<\delta^2 y^2
}.
$$Hence by defining $C=1+\max\{\delta,\delta^2\}$, we complete the proof for $2$-norm and any other norm equivalent to it.

Comment: +1. I suppose many students would not know that any two norms on $\Bbb R^m$  (or on $\Bbb C^m$) with $1\le m<\infty ,$ are uniformly equivalent, But the Q says "arbitrary norm" so you must apply it.